# How do I put data in a two-dimensional array sequentially without duplication?

Tags: python, arrays

I want to put data consisting of a one-dimensional array into a two-dimensional array. I will assume that the number of rows and columns is 5.
The code I tried is as follows.

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
a = []
for i in range(5):
    a.append([])
    for j in range(5):
        a[i].append(j)
print(a)
# result : [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
# I want this : [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [20]]
```

You don't have to worry about the last [20].
The important thing is that the row must change without duplicating the data.
I want to solve it, but I can't think of any way. I ask for your help.

Comment: You can try: 
a[i].append(5*i + j)

Better to store 5 in a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with the current code.

1. It doesn't actually use any of the values from the variable `data`.
2. The data does not contain enough items to populate a `5x5` array.

After adding 0 to the beginning of the variable `data` and using the values from the variable, the code becomes

```py
data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
a = []
for i in range(5):
    a.append([])
    for j in range(5):
        if i*5+j >= len(data):
            break
        a[i].append(data[i*5+j])
print(a)
```

The output of the new code will be

```py
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [20]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should deliever the desired output

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
a = []
x_i = 5
x_j = 5

    for i in range(x_i):
        a.append([])
        for j in range(x_j):
            a[i].append(i*x_j+j)
    print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]
```

Comment: Changed one thing i messed up. Works fine now. Check the result. Just run the code.

Comment: thank you. I think this code will help me a lot

Answer (score 1):

By using list comprehension...

```
data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

columns = 5
rows = 5
result = [data[i * columns: (i + 1) * columns] for i in range(rows)]

print(result)
# [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [20]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `itertools.groupby` with an integer division to create the groups

```py
from itertools import groupby
data = [0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
grouped_data = [list(v) for k, v in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x//5)]
print(grouped_data)
```

**Output**

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [20]]
```

Comment: so best! Can I ask you one more question?

Comment: Of course. If it is related to this question, add it here. If it is sufficiently different, post it as a separate question. And do upvote / accept answers that are helpful.